# Bluetooth COM Ports

Tags: c#, serial-port

When I turn on the bluetooth on my laptop. I see there are 2 ports added under device manager COM&LPT

1. Why does it add 2 ports?
2. If I need to a read/write via bluetooth which port should I consider using?

Thanks.

Comment: Check manufacturer documentation.  One may be a communication port and the other a printer port.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Windows own Bluetooth software, two virtual port COM ports are created after pairing.

I believe one is being used for incoming connection requests and another is used to initiate connections to the device (outgoing).

To determine which one to "use" then please consider [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/13741/bluetooth-module) post which should answer that for you.

Comment: LPT is not a COM port.

Comment: I know LPT is not a COM. Above I said " under device manager COM&LPT" which I was describing the location. Dont you see it say &, How can a COM and LPT be together though.